# How to Get Seldon Sklearn servers to work with Google Cloud Storage from GKE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, seldon

Needed to understand how to make seldon work with prepackaged python pickles and servers.

After following [instructions from seldonio site for sklearn server](https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/servers/sklearn.html), am still unable to get the predefined server models to work.

I have the iris model placed on google cloud storage at location
   -> gcs://mymodels/sklearn/iris.pkl

I successfully installed seldon-core on gke and ran through a wrapped model example successfully. Now I want to be able to use the pre-packaged servers which can pickup python-pickles from google cloud storage.
 When I specify the location to the SeldonDeplymentObject , the service never comes up and the pod continues to die.

Here is my SeldonDeployment:

```
apiVersion: machinelearning.seldon.io/v1alpha2
kind: SeldonDeployment
metadata:
  name: sklearniris
spec:
  name: seldon_skiris
  predictors:
  - graph:
      children: []
      implementation: SKLEARN_SERVER
      modelUri: gcs://mymodels/sklearn/iris.pkl
      name: classifier
    name: default
    replicas: 1
```

What do I setup on gke and gcs to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The error is in SeldonDeployment line `modelUri: gcs://mymodels/sklearn/iris.pkl`. ***gcs*** is not the proper path for Google Cloud storage. It should be `modelUri: gs://mymodels/sklearn/iris.pkl`

Checking the logs for the pod should help see why it continues to die. Describing the pod would also help looking the events for that pod.